# com.xebialabs.deployit.service.importer.ImporterException occuring while importing project using Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, xl-deploy

The following exception is occuring upon importing the project using Jenkins

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.xebialabs.deployit:maven-deployit-plugin:3.8.3:import (default-cli) 
on project INFOGCService: 
Execution default-cli of goal 
com.xebialabs.deployit:maven-deployit-plugin:3.8.3:import failed:
com.xebialabs.deployit.service.importer.ImporterException:
The selected file does not have the expected format for an importable package
```

All proper parameters have been set in pom and deploy-itpom respectively.

deployit-pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>something</groupId>
    <artifactId>deployit-root</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.something.service.war</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectP</artifactId>
<packaging>dar</packaging>
<version>${pom_version}</version>
<name>DAR archive for project ProjectP.</name>
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.something.softwarefactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.something.service.war</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectP</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>2.6.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!-- ============ -->
<!-- Informations -->
<!-- ============ -->
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing some configuration in the `deployit-pom.xml`. You also need to specify the artifacts and/or resources that should be present in the `dar` (See also this [example](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/examples/generate-dar.html)).
And you also might want to update to the latest version of the plugin [v6.0.1](https://dist.xebialabs.com/public/maven2/com/xebialabs/xldeploy/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.1/).